# Show the explicit form of a generated $\sigma$-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> > How can I show that for $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$ and $A_n:=\left\{\left\{1\right\},\ldots,\left\{n\right\}\right\}$ it is
> >     $$
> > \sigma(A_n)=\left\{A\subset\mathbb{N}: A\text{ is finite or }A^C\text{ is finite}\right\}?
> > $$
> >     My thoughts are the following.

I search the *smallest* $\sigma$-Algebra on $\mathbb{N}$ which includes $A_n$. First of all $\mathbb{N}$ and $\emptyset$ have to be in that $\sigma$-Algebra. Then $A_n$ has to be in $\sigma(A_n)$ of course. $A_n$ consists of finite sets, but $\mathbb{N}$ is not finite, but its complement $\emptyset$ is. So my first idea was, that $\sigma(A_n)$ may consist of that sets which are finite or which complements are finite.
And indeed it works, this is already $\sigma$-algebra.

So the way was to look, which sets have to be at least within $\sigma(A_n)$ and then to proof that this is indeed one. But neverhtless it's more intuitive what I did...

What is the professional way to show that?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: As unions of the sets $\{i\}$, $i \le n$ we must have $A \in \sigma(A_n)$ for $A \subseteq \{1,\ldots, n\}$. Moreover we need the complements. Do we need any more, in other words, is 
$$ \bigl\{A \subseteq \mathbb N \mid A \subseteq \{1,\ldots, n\} \lor A^c \subseteq \{1,\ldots, n\} \bigr\} $$
a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Bur whats with $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Your set is the same as $\left\{A\subseteq\mathbb{N}|A\subseteq\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}\vee A^C\cap\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}=\emptyset\right\}$, right? And so, if $A$ is within this set, either $A$ itself or it's complement is finite, right? Because in the first case, $A$ is a subset of a finite set, in the second case $A^C$ is a subset of the finite set $\mathbb{N}\setminus\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$?

Comment: @math12 You're right, I was wrong, corrected.

Comment: I do not see, why the elements of that set fullfill $\subseteq\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$ or their complements fullfill $A^C\cap\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}=\emptyset$, sorry.